# Laravel 4 application minifying files automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to work on a Laravel application and I have static resources in my public folder like so:

```
/public/js/lib/jquery.js
/public/js/home.js
```

The problem is that when they are served just going to the link directly it gets minified automatically. It's becoming an issue when debugging. Has anyone had this similar problem? If so, how can I stop it?

**EDIT**

Just did a fresh install of Laravel on a test server with no dependencies and it is doing this automatically whenever I reference static content. I placed a JS file with comments and when I go to that link directly it removes the comments and spaces from the JS file making everything appear on 1 line. So I know it has nothing to do with the dependencies that I removed that I referenced in my comments on this thread.

Comment: Are you using any asset manager?

Comment: Aren't they supposed to be in `public/assets/js/`?

Comment: I was at first, but then I had removed it from the composer.json file and then ran composer update. and it's still doing it. I was using the asset-pipeline by codesleeve. I thought maybe there would have been files left over, but I made sure to remove all of it's configs and as a provider from my app.php config. Any ideas?

Comment: try clearing the codesleeve cache, I think it's something like `php artisan assets:clean` IIRC. Are you sure you're not still calling the minified js in your views?

Comment: clearing the cache didn't help. I am linking the files directly to the css and js using src="<domain>.com/js/lib/jquery.js"

Comment: You should probably be using `{{ URL::asset('path/to/file.js') }}`